# How to fetch additional models from different URLs into an existing collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I have created a backbone collection like the following:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : MyModel,
    url: 'my_doc.json',
});
```

It works fine. A backbone view create a new `MyCollection` and uses this collection. But `my_doc.json` file will grow up and readability will be decrease. So I want to call different file URLs and merge them in MyCollection collection.

How can I do this.

**my_doc.json** file

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
        "key1": "valueA",
        "key3": "valueB"
    }
]
```

**doc1.json** file

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

**doc2.json** file

```
{
    "key1": "valueA",
    "key3": "valueB"
}
```

Comment: I made an [infinite-collection](https://gist.github.com/emileber/7c3b472fa45d8a208d9a8317bb2f38ae) inspired by [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) that could work, but you'd need to tweak it to work with JSON files instead of query parameters.